# Adding Pagination to Django-Photologue

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, photologue

At the moment Photologue is showing me 4 rows with 5 pictures on each row. I tried modifying it so I only see 5 pictures at once. I tried using `paginate_by = 5` and put it in views.py and urls.py. But neither worked. Can anyone offer suggestions on how to customize the number of rows and columns that are shown?

[image]

**views.py**

```
from photologue.views import PhotoListView
from braces.views import JSONResponseMixin


class PhotoJSONListView(JSONResponseMixin, PhotoListView):
    paginate_by = 5
    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        return self.render_json_object_response(context['object_list'],**response_kwargs)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PhotoJSONListView

from photologue.views import GalleryListView

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^photolist/$',
        PhotoJSONListView.as_view(paginate_by=5),
        name='photologue_custom-photo-json-list'),

path(r'^gallerylist/$',
    GalleryListView.as_view(paginate_by=20),
    name='photologue_custom-gallery-list'),



]
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information please?

1. In your method render_to_response(), can you print the len() of the object_list?
2. I note that url 'photologue_custom-gallery-list' paginates by 20, which is the value you are seeing in the template - is there a possibility that a urls.py elsewhere is mixing up those 2 views? 

PS Having paginate_by in both urls.py and views.py is redundant.

Comment: Hey Richard 

Cheers for the comment. The issue has now been resolved. 

If anyone on StackOverflow is struggling with photologue in the future then they should check out https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-photologue/lM50_XhSmTE.